# make morphia update document with entity properties instead of replacing it (keep not mapped attributes)

Tags: java, mongodb, replace, morphia

Given example document in mongodb collection:

```
{"_id": 100, "name": "User Name", "sideField": "some value"}
```

and Entity for morphia:

```
@Entity()
public class User {
  @Id public long id;
  public String name;
}
```

is it possible to update mongodb document with following example User object

```
User user = new User();
user.id = 100;
user.name = "New Name";
```

so that Morphia would not delete "sideField" attribute?

By default when I use Morphia's Datastore.save(...) method, Morphia replaces whole document under given _id with new one, built from entity, deleting this way all attributes not mapped to entity. I know I can make "manual" updates of selected fields, but that's not why I added Object Mapper to project's dependencies.

Comment: Sadly, that's not possible.

Comment: Thank you @MarkusWMahlberg, that's what I was afraid of. I'll probably fall-back to Morphia.toDBObject(...) then some magic merging with DBObject from database and finally replacing document using standard mongodb api.

Comment: In case you want to change sth, why don't you simply load the original entity?

Comment: Actually the only reason I wanted to create Java Beans from JSON documents was to validate it. Not the whole document, but only small part of it. Maybe I should try https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator - the only java implementation of json-schema spec.

Comment: Maybe you should describe your use case in detail. I am sure we can find a solution.

Comment: A JSON document (simple structure but a lot of fields) comes via REST API to my service. It can be a new document to store in MongoDB or an update of already existing doc. I have to validate it and store. Update should touch only attributes it contains (no deleting of other fields).

Comment: Same use case here. Underlying document gets modified by two separate REST apis, each api updating orthogonal attributes. Due to the morphia limitation had to split the document into two, even though I wanted to keep it as one document.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have dropped Morphia and solved problem using MongoDB Java driver API 3.0.0 and Jackson like this:

```
String updateJson = .... //I get JSON String via REST API
// here, if I want to validate update I use JSON Schema 
// or Jackson (to map updateJson to object and validate it with javax.validation)
Document updateDoc = Document.parse(updateJson);
Document setUpdate = new Document("$set", updateDoc);
mongoDb.getCollection("COLL").updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", someID), setUpdate);
```

Of course this works only for simple updates but is enough for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an update instead of a save. For this update, however, you will need a query which identifies your object:

```
update(Query<T> q, UpdateOperations<T> updateOptions);
```

Then on the object you get from the REST API you need to go through all the model attributes (in your case name, id, sideField) and add to the updateOperations the ones which are not null:

```
//User fetched from the REST API.
User user = fetchUserFromAPI(...);
UpdateOperations<T> updateOptions = ds.createUpdateOperations(User.class);
if(user.name != null){updateOptions.set("name", user.name);}
if(user.name != null){updateOptions.set("sideField", user.sideField);}
ds.update(ds.createQuery(User.class).field("_id").equal(user.id), updateOptions);
```

That code above will update in your DB with `_id == user.id` the fields name and sideField if they are not empty.

Of course you could add this code as a method on your model and use reflection to get all the attributes from the model and then check if they are not and in case they are not, add them to the UpdateOperations.

Comment: Thx, but there is no object mapping in this method and I don't need Morphia for it. I can do it directly in MongoDB driver's API.